# Move focus from one to another itemRenderer inside DataGrid itemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I have a mx: DataGrid with 4 columns that have a itemRenderer with the following settings:

Mx:DataGrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="itensPedidoCompraList"
             width="100%"
             height="120"    
             dataProvider="{ model.pedidoCompra.itens }"
             editable="true"
             itemEditEnd="itensPedidoCompraList_itemEditEndHandler(event)">
```

Mx:DataGridColumn:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="{resourceManager.getString('cadastroPedidoCompra', 'ident.PercentualDesconto') }"
               width="60"
               textAlign="right"
               rendererIsEditor="true"
               editorDataField="data">
  <mx:itemRenderer>
             <fx:Component>
                   <mx:Canvas>
                         <input:NumberInput width="55"   number="@{data.percentualDesconto }"/>
                   </mx:Canvas>
        </fx:Component>
  </mx:itemRenderer>
```

The user clicks on the line of the grid and click on the column to edit.
After him change or add value, ENTER key and have to move the focus to another column in the same line.
The way I'm doing, is moving to the column below.

What is the best way to do to move to the right column?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note that the DataGrid has the following functionality when editing rows:

- <kbd>Enter</kbd> accepts the edit and moves focus to next row (if `editorUsesEnterKey` is true)
- <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> accepts the edit and moves focus to next/previous column
- <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> cancels the edit leaving focus in place

You can disable the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key functionality with the [editorUsesEnterKey](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#editorUsesEnterKey) property of the `DataGridColumn`.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn editorUsesEnterKey="false" />
```

Changing the behavior so that `ENTER` moves focus to right/left is a bit hairy. The key stroke handling is done in the private method below. This listener is added in the `DataGrid`'s public method `createItemEditor()` and removed in `destroyItemEditor()`. Theoretically, you could override these methods to change this behavior.

Source mx::DataGrid (note tabbing is handled in a key focus change handler)

```
 private function editorKeyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        // ESC just kills the editor, no new data
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE)
        {
            endEdit(DataGridEventReason.CANCELLED);
        }
        else if (event.ctrlKey && event.charCode == 46)
        {   // Check for Ctrl-.
            endEdit(DataGridEventReason.CANCELLED);
        }
        else if (event.charCode == Keyboard.ENTER && event.keyCode != 229)
        {
            // multiline editors can take the enter key.
            if (!_editedItemPosition)
                return;

            if (columns[_editedItemPosition.columnIndex].editorUsesEnterKey)
                return;

            // Enter edits the item, moves down a row
            // The 229 keyCode is for IME compatability. When entering an IME expression,
            // the enter key is down, but the keyCode is 229 instead of the enter key code.
            // Thanks to Yukari for this little trick...
            if (endEdit(DataGridEventReason.NEW_ROW) && !dontEdit)
                findNextEnterItemRenderer(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It worked partially. Added the editorUsesEnterKey = "true" and within the itemEditEnd I do this:
   itensPedidoCompraList.editedItemPosition = {columnIndex:event.columnIndex + 1 , rowIndex:0};

My itemRenderer has a component that NumberInput extends TextInput, when I do editedItemPosition he throws the focus out of the DataGrid. The focus will only when the column and not an itemRenderer.

Comment: PS: Or just rely on the fact that the `TAB` key moves the focus horizontally. It's actually pretty standard behavior. You can tell your client the grid behaves like Excel: when you press `Enter` it moves down one row :)

Comment: I understand. But the requirement and use the Enter key.
Even the Tab key does not move to the next itemRenderer and shows no focus. So move to another itemRenderer that has a TextInput.
I'm guessing it is something related to my custom component that extends TextInput. If you use TextInput works normally.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like your custom renderer that extends TextInput is why the tab key doesn't work properly. You might want to create a new question or/edit this one and show the code for that renderer.